# list circles seems above from list items when float and list-style properties used together in ul li a

Tags: html, css, styles, css-float, html-lists

I defined `float:left;` and their width/height's to all elements. When i try to position list circles in to unordered list. **Result outcome:** Circles above from `li a`

**Here is problem:** http://jsfiddle.net/SPwyc/17/

**Without** `float:left` it is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/SPwyc/18/

But i want to fix this with `float:left`, i've tried to add `display:block` and `display:inline` but it didn't work either.

Comment: If you have one working properly, what's the problem?

Comment: Need to solve it with `float:left` property mate, read the question.

Comment: Why do you need to solve it with float? Are the LIs meant to line up next to each other?

Comment: Why is the 'css reset' bit _after_ your css, it renders some of your css pointless!

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Because on my work, i have some complicated properties on that element which depends on `float:left` property. Thats why i need it.

Comment: @Timm you can remove it if you want, outcome won't be different. I put reset css to show you, in case of my reset css is bugged.

Comment: Do you need the `float:left` on the `a` tag?

Comment: @Timm Yeap, needed on all of `ul li a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed if you add `position: absolute;` to the `a` tag, but I don't know if that will ruin any of your other styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/SPwyc/23/